# sql if-else procedure prob, cant create procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delimiter//
create procedure exercise(out stat char(10),out fee double)
begin
    if stat=='AC executive' then set fee=100;
    else if stat=='AC Economi' then set fee=50;
    else set saldo=20;
    end if;
end//
delimiter;
```

Comment: what dialect is that? oracle, ms, mysql?

Comment: replace == with = and you havent defined saldo

Comment: man... i've been out of mysql for a minute but shouldn't that be a case statement?  (it's late, i might be wrong)

Comment: those are both `out` parameters.... is that what you wanted?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: error 1064(42000) error syntax;it suggested me to check manually mysql server version for the right syntax use near 'delimeter// error at line 1

Comment: @gloomy.penguin smells like a case expression to me too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if-else if`  is not correct it should be

```
if condition then do something
elseif condition then do something
else do something
```

There is no space between `elseif`. Also I suppose you mean `fee` not `saldo` in the else part. And `out stat char(10)` should be `in stat varchar(100)`, since you are using the param as input

```
delimiter //
create procedure exercise(in stat varchar(100),out fee double)
begin
    if stat ='AC executive' then set fee=100;
    elseif stat = 'AC Economi' then set fee=50;
    else set fee=20;
    end if;
end;//

delimiter;
```

Here is a test on mysql

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure exercise(in stat varchar(100),out fee double)
    -> begin
    ->     if stat ='AC executive' then set fee=100;
    ->     elseif stat = 'AC Economi' then set fee=50;
    ->     else set fee=20;
    ->     end if;
    -> end;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;


mysql> call exercise('AC executive',@o);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @o ;
+------+
| @o   |
+------+
|  100 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```